# How to avoid UICollectionView repeating cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hello I have a `UICollectionView`. I load data from a `NSMutableArray` and it has 4 objects. But my problem is its repeating the same cells again.

`

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return mutArrayArtists.count;
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 2;
 }



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

artist = [mutArrayArtists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = artist.artistImage;

UILabel *lblArtistname=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
lblArtistname.text=artist.artistName;

UILabel *lblSongCount=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
lblSongCount.text=artist.numberofSongs;
return cell;
 }
```

`

But the result is like this
[image]

How can I avoid this? Please help me

Thanks

Comment: It shows the count as 4

Comment: you have declared to have two sections in your collectionView, but in `numberOfItemsInSection`and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you are not taking into consideration the section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;  //instead of 2
}
```

The section here does not mean the number of columns. It means that the collection view will contain 2 sections vertically above each others

Comment: ohh thanks I thought its refer the two columns. Thats why I put 2 there. Thank you somuch. 5 more minuts to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 2;
}
```

You have two sections to the collection view, and in your cell provider, you don't distinguish the sections. Change it to say `return 1;` (assuming you do want just one section in the collection) or update the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function (by inspecting `indexPath.section`) to split the sections out as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView

    {

        return 1;
    }
```